# How to combine ggshield and Husky for pre-commit git hook?

Tags: javascript, git, pre-commit, pre-commit.com, husky

I want to combine ggshield(by GitGuardian) and Husky into one pre-commit hook, but the result is that only one of them works.

I tried run `pre-commit install` in repo and after this run `husky install` in repo. In that case when i tryed to make commit with test errors Husky work but ggshield don't work.

Also after that i tried run `git config --unset-all core.hooksPath` for unset git hooks in repo, and run `husky install` in repo, and after this run `pre-commit install` and received an error: `Cowardly refusing to install hooks with 'core.hooksPath' set`.

After this i run `git config --unset-all core.hooksPath` and then run `pre-commit install` then ggshield will work. But as soon as I run the `husky install` command, Husky starts working and ggshield stops working.

It turns out that only one of the git hooks can work at a time? Or is there some way to combine them?

Comment: `pre-commit` by default will also run the pre-existing husky hooks when they were installed first -- are you not seeing that? (so `husky install && pre-commit install` should do what you want) -- unless husky is automatically modifying `core.hooksPath` which seems quite a bad choice on their part

Comment: @Albert: anthony sottile: I described what would happen in this case: error `Cowardly refusing to install hooks with 'core.hooksPath' set`.

Answer (score 1):

A Husky pre-commit hook is a shell script called `.husky/pre-commit`. To add ggshield to an existing hook, open your `.husky/pre-commit` file and append the following line to it:

```
ggshield secret scan pre-commit
```